# Saving domain entities changes

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository, entity, cqrs

here's real example that will lead to my question: I have an AddCommentToArticleCommand, which has an ArticleId, comment text and email address. This command:

- uses the article repository to get the article (which is the domain entity)
- if  article exists, it calls article.AddComment(commentText, emailAddress), which adds the comment to the article and throws exception when it can't (due to invalid email format, article was closed, comment not filled in or too long etc...)
- but now I don't know what the best way is to save the added comment?

Should I do something like articleRepository.Save(article)? But then, why should I save the article if only a comment was added? Or can I do something like articleRepository.SaveComment(comment), that will only save the comment? Or what approach would you take here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [MattDavey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496094/saving-domain-entities-changes/7496407#7496407) points out, in DDD you usually think about [Aggregate](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88) life cycle, not about CRUD persistence issues. The middle and end of life of the Aggregate is handled by a corresponding [Repository](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/123). Regarding your specific question:

> but now I don't know what the best way is to save the added comment?

The best way to handle this is to find a reliable ORM and implement your

```
articles.MakePersistent(article)
```

repository method using this ORM. Good ORM will implement [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), will include dirty tracking, lazy loading and other persistence related issues without constraining your domain objects. **ORM knows how to avoid not needed SQL INSERT/UPDATEs when saving the Aggregate**. Your domain objects should be as persistent ignorant as possible. The only constraint that NHibernate, for example, puts on your objects is that they should have private default constructor. Other than that they can be simple POCO objects unaware of all the persistence issues. Just to clear, domain objects should not have `IsTransient` or `IsDirty` flags. And if you find yourself writing code that uses these flags you are [reinveting the wheel](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).

Comment: You have helped me with your comment, because I realized I was doing things that already exist. So I changed the approach: I use entity framework with code first; and implemented unit of work pattern. So now the EF context is keeping the changes for me. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Dmitry +1 this is a very valid point. In my particular circumstances I can't make any assumptions about the capabilities of the ORM being used (it might not even be an ORM), so it makes sense for me to implement things such as change tracking in the domain. If you're sufficiently tied to an ORM implementation that you can reliably leverage it's features then of course it makes a lot of sense to do so :)

Comment: Actually, my domain is not dependent on the ORM, or anything else. It's the center of the onion architecture. The unit of work that is built around it, is dependent on the ORM, and uses its context for change tracking. But the domain only has domain logic...

Comment: @Dmitry Does my answer below (which clearly violates the principle of persistance ignorance) contradict DDD? Take my scenario for example where, as I mentioned, I can make no assumptions about the capabilities of the data access layer.. does it make sense in DDD to hoist features such as change tracking into the domain model? Or perhaps there should be another layer between the domain model and the DAL to handle things like this (& lazy loading, unit of work etc).
`@Lud sorry for hijacking your question but I'd really like to know where I went so wrong with my answer :)

Comment: I think it does because change tracking is a persistence issue that should not be 'bleeding' on your domain. It should be implemented by ORM, whether you are using existing one or trying to build your own. Building domain layer where objects are persisted in a relational database is very very hard without ORM. Your objects would become more and more persistence-aware and lose domain focus. The same thing happens however on most 'home grown' ORM projects. Putting change tracking into domain was most likely the reason your answer got downvoted (once) (not by me).

Comment: I guess DDD may not be appropriate for my particular circumstances then. I agree that certain features/tasks should be handled by the ORM, but for me I can't make this assumption - my data access layer may or may not be an ORM, it may be a message queue, XML file or NOSQL db... the *only* guarantee I have is that the DAL can populate a hierarchy of DTO objects, so I'm forced to implement things like change tracking myself. Whether or not that should be in the domain model probably deserves its own question :)

Answer (score 1):

In DDD it's often the case that you take the entire composition hierarchy from the aggregate root down and treat it as a single entity. So, adopting that mentality, *"why should I save the article if only a comment was added?"*, it would seem that the article as a whole has changed, and the representation of the article in the database is stale. Ideally you would replace the whole composition hierarchy in the database (with a document database this would be fine), however this could lead to performance problems in a relational DB.

In that case you might decide to have the repository scan over the composition of the entity, aggregate root down, and intelligently decide what to do with each component. You could use the visitor pattern to iterate through the Comment objects, and depending on whether or not they are transient/dirty, decide to do an insert or update, or just to leave them alone..

I hope I've been clear enough, I'm not so good at explaining conceptual things :)

EDIT: Code sample:

```
// In ArticleRepository...
public void Save(Article article)
{
    // IsTransient (as opposed to IsPersistant) means "has not yet been saved"...
    if (article.IsTransient)
    {
        DB.InsertArticle(article);
        // Inserting the article also inserts any comments / sub components...
    }
    else
    {
        // IsDirty means "has been modified since it was taken from the DB"...
        if (article.IsDirty)
        {
            DB.UpdateArticle(article);
        }

        foreach(var comment in article.Comments)
        {
            if(comment.IsTransient)
            {
                DB.InsertComment(article.Id, comment);
            }
            else
            {
                if (comment.IsDirty)
                {
                    DB.UpdateComment(comment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess it means that the entity should update these IsTransient and IsDirty properties if if properties change; and the repository is responsible for resetting them after saving the entity?

Comment: yep indeed, check out the System.ComponentModel.IChangeTracking interface. IsTransient/IsPersistant can sometimes be deduced by the lack of/existance of a primary key value respectively..

Comment: In my entities I often also implement ISupportInitialize, when the entity is being initialized, changing properties does not make the entity dirty (or raise property changed event etc). This can be quite handy too :)

Comment: But if there's a key, I don't need IsTransient I guess - I can just check the id, if it's 0 it means that IsTransient is true...  so the IChangeTracking seems good enough...

Comment: By the way, how would you handle the deletion of a comment?

Comment: ok, i just added an EntityState to each entity, which can be New, Modified, Deleted, Unmodified. Based on that, the articlerepository makes the decisions...

Comment: Meanwhile I did not do it like this, because it seemed strange to implement something that in fact can be done by the ORM...

Comment: 2x downvoters please explain, and let me know what I have misunderstood?

Comment: This old example is exactly how relational persistence should **not** be done. Iterating will lead to flooding the database with single roundtrip statements for each iteration step, also called SELECT N+1. Dependencies might not be available at save time. An ORM is there to do this in the background, much better.